# Get params value from number_field_tag in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In code:

```
<%@menus.each do |d|%>

<%= number_field_tag :quantity%>

<%= button_to 'ADD', {:controller=>'line_items',:action=>'create',:menu_id=>d.id,
:quantity=>params[:quantity]},:remote=>true%>
```

I am new in rails.I want the value from this `number_field_tag` in this button. That's why I used `params[:quantity]` in the button but I'm getting nothing there.

Comment: start using `form_for` or `form_tag`

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want the value from this number_field_tag in this button'? What do you want to happen when you click the 'ADD' button?

Comment: when i click on the add button the quantity should add to the line_items